# Mongoose method findbyIdAndRemove is failing when called client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a route in my app that calls the mongoose method findByIdAndRemove. When I test this route in postman, I can successfully delete documents in my database, but when I call this method from my javascript file in the client, I get an error.

I getting a 404 (the response status I dictated if no document can be found). I also get an error in the terminal saying "can't set headers after they are sent." I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Why is my route working in postman, but not when I call it from the client-side?

How should I get this working?

Here is my route on the server-side:

```
exports.deleteEmployee = function (req, res, next) {
  const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id);

      Employee.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err, employee) => {
          if (err) { return next(err); }

          // if no employee with the given ID is found throw 400
          if (!employee) { res.status(404).json('No employee with that ID'); }

          res.status(200).json(employee);
      });
    };
```

Here is where I call this route from the client-side:

```
export const employeeDelete = ({ id }) => {
  const props = { id };

  return () => {
    axios.delete(`${api.API_ROUTE}/employee/delete`, props)
      .then(() => {
        // push user back to EmployeeList and reset view stack
        Actions.employeeList({ type: 'reset' });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you verified that `${api.API_ROUTE}/employee/delete` is resolving to the same URL you are using in postman by logging this value to the console?

Comment: Yea I've done that.

Comment: And you're using a DELETE method in postman?

Comment: Yes, I'm using delete in postman as well.

Comment: Have you confirmed that in both cases you're getting the id?

Comment: Yes I get the id in both cases

Comment: Last question and then I'm out of ideas. Is the 404 you get definitely coming from axios? I.e., you get the custom error message?

Comment: Larry, yes I get the custom error message because I changed the status from 404 to 401 to test just exactly that.

Comment: Turns out I was not getting the ID. I tested the wrong route when I console.logged the ID, but I'm still sure that I get the custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting  "can't set headers after they are sent." error because you're trying to respond with 200 code after having responded with 400 code.

You should surround the response statements with a if/else statement:

```
if (!employee) { res.status(404).json('No employee with that ID'); }
else{res.status(200).json(employee);}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but why does this work in postman, in terms of deleting a document, but from the client side it doesn't work. I'll get back a 200 but no document in the database gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the axios delete method does not take a data object, so when I passed the object called props, it never reached the server. I instead passed id as a url parameter like this:

```js
export const employeeDelete = ({ id }) => {
  return () => {
    axios.delete(`${api.API_ROUTE}/employee/delete/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        // push user back to EmployeeList and reset view stack
        Actions.employeeList({ type: 'reset' });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```